# Passing parameter in URL in Lightning component and community pages

Tags: community, lightning-community, pagereference, community-builder

will it work in  community pages, if yes then  how, can you brief me?

this is url and i am passing parameter in it as key= sunil
https://deb1-coro.cs17.force.com/v2/s/invdetail?key=sunil

var pageReference = component.get('v.pageReference');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(pageReference));

but getting null as log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not supported in communities

> This pageReference feature is supported only in Salesforce Lightning
>   and the Salesforce App.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:hasPageReference/documentation